# Android App with 2 library with jniLibs - crash the app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In my android App, I use two libraries which each has its own jniLibs.

library 1 - https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidPdfViewer

library 2 - custom video player sdk

The app will compile and build fine.

both library has the jniLibs in the correct place.

It seems that only one library will work, in this case the pdfView. The the library 2 is called. it breaks and the log say it can not load the jniLibs for it.

Does anyone has ever came across it ? thanks

> Update code after chaeyoungx feedback:

**App Build.gradle:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 14
    versionName "1.0"

    ndk { abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "mips" }
}
   ....
```

I tried this following code in both files: gradle.properties (Project and Global)

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

> > Still have the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure, you have your libraries built for every abi. Look at your final apk file. In the folder libs you'll find folders with libs for each abi. There should be the same libraries in each one.
In case you don't have enough:

1. build your libraries for other abis
2. exclude these folders, i.e.

   ```
   armeabi
       lib1.so
       lib2.so
       lib3.so
   armeabi-v7a
       lib1.so
       lib2.so
       lib3.so
   arm64-v8a
       lib1.so
   ```

In this situation arm64 device will go to arm64-v8a folder and try to find lib2, lib3, and won't find them. So exclude arm64-v8a folder in java application's gradle file, so arm64 device could use armeabi folder.

Answer (score 6):

I also tried to import 2 libraries for my application and had the same error.

I found the solution on the net and here is how I solved problem:

1. go to gradle.properties and add android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
2. then open build.gradle which is in your app folder then enter

   ```
   ndk {
       abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
   }
   ```

   inside defaultconfig{

After this I just clean and rebuilt the project and worked without error.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have updated my code above, Still having the same problem.

Comment: @Joolah  I also had problem with sdk version 23. SDK 23 couldn't locate jnilibs. Try downgrading to 4.4 and then try to compile